# Error using rhandsontable in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I've observed some strange behaviour of `rhandsontable` in a shiny app. In this simple example I am assigning a `data.frame` to a `reactiveValues` element if some event happens. The data is then shown in a `rhandsontable`. But when I change some entry of the table the function `hot_to_r` fails with: **Error in seq.default: argument 'length.out' must be of length 1**

Strangely the error only happens if I use `iris`, but not when I use `iris[1:50, ]`, which should be identical. Does somebody have an idea, how to fix this?

(There is another error when `values$data` is still `NULL` before the `actionButton` is clicked. I'm aware of this, but this is not relevant for the question.)

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("click", "click"),
  rHandsontableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  values <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$click, {
    values$data <- iris # with iris[1:50, ] no error appears
  })

  output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(t(values$data))
  })

  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$table$changes$changes)) {
      table_data <- hot_to_r(input$table)
      print(table_data)
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I guess the error comes from transposing the data. Check: `t(head(iris))`. Why are you transposing, to adapt the table output?

Comment: The data.frame I'm actually using only has one row, so I think the table output looks better transposed. And this fits better in a column design, when I want to have other ui elements next to the table.

Comment: You can get the modified dataset with `as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, input$table$data))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BigDataScientist is on to something, `colnames(t(iris))` is `NULL`, whereas `colnames(t(iris[1:50,]))` is not. That is a mystery to me, but preventing that nullness should resolve your problem.  Using something in the call to `rhandsontable` should do the trick.  Using

```
rhandsontable(data.frame(t(values$data)))
```

worked for me.